# How to use ImgBB api with Axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to use the Imgbb API to upload images but so far I have been unable to do so.
The API docs showed this as an example call:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=60&key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" --form "image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

So my axis:

```js
vendorImageUpload(img) {
    var responseArr = []
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("image", img)
    formData.append("key", "api-key")

    console.log(axios({
      method: "post",
      url: IMG_URL,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      }
    }))
  }
```

But I am getting a 400 error. However, when I test it with postman it works when the only things in the header are `content-type`, `content-length` and `host`.

I wanted to use `formData.getHeaders()` cause that apparently worked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998715/how-to-post-form-data-using-axios-in-node), but it only works on Node and not react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue was from setting the formdata.

```js
uploadImage(img) {
    let body = new FormData()
    body.set('key', 'an_api_key')
    body.append('image', img)

    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload',
      data: body
    })
  }
```

This works fine and returns the data the way I want. To Sajal, thank you for answering the question, I actually figured it out a while ago. However, I didn't want to add another NPM library for something this simple.

The response will look like this:

```
{
  id: '5jKj6XV',
  url_viewer: 'https://ibb.co/5jKj6XV',
  url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
  display_url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
  title: 'test',
  time: '1574431312',
  image: {
    filename: 'test.jpg',
    name: 'test',
    mime: 'image/jpeg',
    extension: 'jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
    size: 91264
  },
  thumb: {
    filename: 'test.jpg',
    name: 'test',
    mime: 'image/jpeg',
    extension: 'jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/5jKj6XV/test.jpg',
    size: '12875'
  },
  delete_url: 'https://ibb.co/5jKj6XV/ffd8ef0b1c803f02443553535cf4a5f4'
}
```

Then the data can be stored using `.then` after the function call.

```js
...


uploadImage(e.target.files[0])
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data.data) // I'm aware it's data.data, that is how it returns stuff
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an npm library `imgbb-uploader`.

```
var imgbbUploader = require('imgbb-uploader');

imgbbUploader("your-imgbb-api-key-string", "home/absolute/path/to/your/image/image.png")
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(1))
```

**The response will be something like this.**

```
{
  id: '5jKj6XV',
  url_viewer: 'https://ibb.co/5jKj6XV',
  url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
  display_url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
  title: 'test',
  time: '1574431312',
  image: {
    filename: 'test.jpg',
    name: 'test',
    mime: 'image/jpeg',
    extension: 'jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/94Z4Nmj/test.jpg',
    size: 91264
  },
  thumb: {
    filename: 'test.jpg',
    name: 'test',
    mime: 'image/jpeg',
    extension: 'jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/5jKj6XV/test.jpg',
    size: '12875'
  },
  delete_url: 'https://ibb.co/5jKj6XV/ffd8ef0b1c803f02443553535cf4a5f4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To post an image to imgbb api you need to encode the image in base64 string, for that you can use `FileReader()`. See below:

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const rf = new FileReader();
    rf.readAsDataURL(file); //file is from a useState() hook
    rf.onloadend = function (event) {
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append("image", event.target.result.split(",").pop()); //To delete 'data:image/png;base64,' otherwise imgbb won't process it.
        body.append("name", fileName);
        fetch(imgUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: body
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.json().then(console.log));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
})
```

In my case I got the file from `<input>`, you can also open a file locally.
Don't forget to use `res.json().then()` if you want to use the response from imgbb