# POST image to django rest API always returns 'No file was submitted'

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, axios

I am trying to get this working now for days -.-

Using a simple NodeJS express server, I want to upload an image to a Django instance through Post request, but I just can't figure out, how to prepare the request and embed the file.

Later I would like to post the image, created from a canvas on the client side,
but for testing I was trying to just upload an existing image from the nodeJS server.

```
app.post('/images', function(req, res) {

    const filename = "Download.png"; // existing local file on server

    // using formData to create a multipart/form-data content-type
    let formData = new FormData();
    
    let buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    formData.append("data", buffer); // appending the file a buffer, alternatively could read as utf-8 string and append as text
    
    formData.append('name', 'var name here'); // someone told me, I need to specify a name
    
    const config = {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }

    axios.post("http://django:8000/images/", formData, config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("success!"); // never happens :(
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data); // no file was submitted
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong or did I just miss something?

**EDIT**

I just found a nice snippet with a slighlty other approach on the npm form-data page, on the very bottom (npmjs.com/package/form-data):

```js
const filename = "Download.png"; // existing local file on server

let formData = new FormData();

let stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
formData.append('data', stream)

let formHeaders = formData.getHeaders()

axios.post('http://django:8000/images/', formData, {
    headers: {
        ...formHeaders,
    },
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("success!"); // never happens :(
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data); // no file was submitted
});
```

sadly, this doesn't change anything :( I still receive only Bad Request: No file was submitted

I don't really have much Django code just a basic setup using the rest_framework with an image model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    data = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Image Resource"
```

which are also registered in the admin.py,
a serializer:

```
from .models import Image


class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id', 'data')
```

using automatic URL routing.

I wrote a simple test script and put the same image on the django server, to verify that image uploads works, and it does:

```py
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/"

file = {'data': open('Download.png', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=file)


print(response.status_code) # 201
```

Comment: I think the error could be in the backend side and how the form data is being processed. If you can share the backend code too.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am wondering if you managed to identify the root cause and found a better solution?

Comment: @desa nah, I didn't manage to identify what caused the problem, I ended up using unirest. But thanks for your answer, your solution seems very promising!

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for accepting it! In the case you find a better solution, please share it. It also works now for my case, but it would be still interesting to figure out why it does not work with `axios`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem: I used the same Django endpoint to upload a file using `axios` 1) from the client side and 2) from the server side. From the client side it worked without any problem, but from the server side, the request body was always empty.

My solution was to use the following code:

```
      const fileBuffer = await readFile(file.filepath)

      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('file', fileBuffer, file.originalFilename)

      const response = await fetch(
        urlJoin(BACKEND_URL),
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
          },
        }
      )
```

A few relevant references that I found useful:

1. [This blog post](https://maximorlov.com/send-a-file-with-axios-in-nodejs/), even though it seems the author manages to send form data from the server side using axios, I did not manage to reproduce it on my case.
2. [This issue report](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1321) in the axio repository, where one comment suggests to use `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

In your node.js express server instead of adding the image to the form data, try directly sending the stream in the API post.

```
const filename = "Download.png"; // existing local file on server

//let formData = new FormData();

let stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
//formData.append('data', stream)

let formHeaders = formData.getHeaders()

axios.post('http://django:8000/images/', stream, {
    headers: {
        ...formHeaders,
    },
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("success!"); // never happens :(
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data); // no file was submitted
});
```

Comment: if I don't use the formData at all (and so the formHeaders, which would throw an error if not also commented out) I am receiving the same error. Which is kinda strange, because  I remember I read this is needed to be able to set the boundary for the multipart-data and was an error I received before [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998715/how-to-post-form-data-using-axios-in-node)

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't manage to get this working with axios so I tried another package for sending files as post requests, namely [unirest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unirest), which worked out of the box for me.

Also it is smaller, requires less code and does everything I needed:

```js
const filename = "Download.png"; // existing local file on server

unirest
    .post(url)
    .attach('data', filename) // reads directly from local file
    //.attach('data', fs.createReadStream(filename)) // creates a read stream
    //.attach('data', fs.readFileSync(filename)) // 400 - The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form. -> maybe check encoding?
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body) // 201
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data));
```

If I have some spare time in the future I may look into what was wrong with my axios implementation or someone does know a solution pls let me know :D